# xcuitest- Trying to tap on a link within a linklabel

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, xcuitest

I am trying to tap on a link within a link label. Using the recorder I have this code for the tap event

`let link = XCUIApplication().scrollViews.otherElements.links["link here"]`

`link.tap()` does not tap on the link correctly. The link is at the end of the text, how would I be able to tap that part of the label? It seems like XCUITest taps the start of the text which doesnt have the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it may be an accessibility container issue. However one work around is to compute the coordinate relative to the UI element you can access with `XCUIApplication`.

```
let coordinate = CGVector(dx: 0.1, dy: 0.1) //Enter your values for x / y
someElement.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: coordinate).tap()
```

I usually just use trial and error to compute the coordinates. However, you can use the accessibility inspector and debug prints if you need an extra precise press.